# desktop icons on win 8.1 appear white

Tags: icons, desktop

Some of the icons on the desktop are normal others suddenly appeared as white squares.
I tried changing the registry entry: `exefile\shellex\iconhandler`.

However there is no `iconhandler` to change?

Comment: Try running DISM and SFC.   Remember Windows 8 is dead and no more updates.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Tried all of the suggestions, Got same reply for all: "Elevated permissions are required to run, use an elevated command prompt to complete these tasks."

Answer (score 0):

If all the above failed, then a more comprehensive repair is necessary.

Windows 8 is out of support and rebuilding it is most likely not a good idea.

Windows 8 machines should (>75%) run Windows 10.

So download the Windows 10 ISO

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

and install Windows 10.  Be sure (very sure) to back everything up first.